# Score var updates double randomly

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, ios9, sprite

I'm making a game, and currently I'm working on the scoring system. However, I'm facing a stupid problem. My score var always when is called to increase the value with the unary operator (+=) by 1, it sometimes updates the value by 2 points, instead of 1, and it's doing it randomly. I have written a protocol, which I'm conforming to my GameScene class, and I'm calling that method always when there is a contact between the sprites.

```
func wasCollected(item: gold) {

    score += item.pointValue
}
```

Could be this method called twice instead of once? Because in the console I see the numbers update sequentially by 2 when I try to collect a single point at random moments. I've tried also to fix this by using score++ only instead of accessing the item.pointValue property, but the problem still exists.

Here is a method that I'm calling while setting the text property in my custom class and according to my breakpoint i'm getting a character twice with a single execution of the method. What I'm doing wrong? Basically what I'm doing with this method, I have a bitmap graphics which I'm using as a font for my numbers.

```
        for var i:NSInteger = 0; i < text.length; i++
        {

            //Get character in text for current position in loop
            //Getting the scalar encoded value
            let scalarEncoded:unichar = text.characterAtIndex(i)
            //Decoding the scalar
            let scalarDecoded = Character(UnicodeScalar(scalarEncoded))
            //Build texture name from character and font name
            let textureName:NSString = "\(fontName)\(scalarDecoded)"
            print(textureName)

            if i < children.count
            {
                //Reuse existing node
                letter = children[i] as! SKSpriteNode
                letter.texture = graphicsAtlas.textureNamed(textureName as String)
                letter.size = letter.texture!.size()
            }
            else
            {
                //Create a new node if not exist
                letter = SKSpriteNode(texture: graphicsAtlas.textureNamed(textureName as String))
                letter.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
                self.addChild(letter)
            }
            letter.position = pos
            pos.x += letter.size.width + letterSpacing
            totalSize.width = letter.size.width + letterSpacing

            if totalSize.height < letter.size.height
            {
                totalSize.height = letter.size.height
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your issue would not be caused from this function, either you have changed the value of item.pointValue to more than one somewhere or you are calling the function twice as you hypothesised - could you please post the code where this function is called.

Comment: you could also set a simple breakpoint in that method to check if it is being executed more than once

Comment: @BlakeLockley I posted the method above Blake.

Comment: sorry could you post the block where the function `wasCollected` is being called